# Guarantee primary key is present in update trigger

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am writing an update trigger and accessing the 'inserted' table to see which rows have been modified.

I have two related questions :

1. Does the inserted table always contain all the columns of the real table?
2. If the inserted table contains only the columns that have changed, will there always at least be the primary key columns in the inserted table?

Comment: 1. Yes. It contains a copies of all inserted rows. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it includes all columns from the original table, [except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx):

> SQL Server 2012 does not allow for **text**, **ntext**, or **image** column references in the inserted and deleted tables for AFTER triggers.

(Similar language, with different version numbers, exists for older versions of SQL Server)

Ask yourself how useful they would be if only a single (non-key) column was updated. You could tell that an update had occurred but you'd be unable to do any further useful processing.